# how to add styles to input radio element inside label is it possible?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="radio-toolbar">
 <label for="mylabel-1"><input type="radio" id="mybutton-1"  checked>All</label>
 <label for="mylabel-2"><input type="radio" id="mybutton-2"  >Open</label>
 <label for="mylabel-2"><input type="radio" id="mybutton-3"  >Archived</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**i want add css styles to input radio button inside label,i don't want to add css to outside label  **
**is it possible?**

Comment: yes `label input[type=radio]{ ... }`

Comment: can u give an example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

`label input[type=radio]{
  display:none;
}`

Further more ,you need to use this (use same name for radio buttons to select only one.Otherwise, it looks like checkboxes)

```
 <label for="mylabel-1"><input name="rd" type="radio" id="mybutton-1"  checked>All</label>
 <label for="mylabel-2"><input name="rd" type="radio" id="mybutton-2"  >Open</label>
 <label for="mylabel-2"><input name="rd" type="radio" id="mybutton-3"  >Archived</label>
```

Comment: thank for(use same name for radio buttons to select only one.Otherwise, it looks like checkboxes)  and dislpay:none is working can u add color:red,then tell is it work or not